# How to get callback when section of sound has been played in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio

So I have started creating a "sound map", which is a sound file consisting of many sound clips (100 sound clips concatenated in this case). They are stored in a single mp3 file. What I'm wondering tho is, how do you tell when one sound has finished playing?

Basically what I have is a map of clip name to `duration` and `startTime`. You could easily just do `setTimeout(callback, duration)` once the sound has started playing, but there is often lag and the browser `setTimeout` doesn't 100% align with the audio playback performance. Is there any way I can sort of have the audio encoding itself tell the browser to emit events at certain points in the track? If so, how do I go about encoding that with ffmpeg or some tool? If not, what to do?

Basically I want to emit events when subchunks of the complete track are completed, so I can stop the playing. This will make it possible to create a single track composed of many sound clips concatenated together, and I can just jump to different places in the track. But the problem I'm facing is how do you know exactly when the sub-clip has finished playing? It's like I need the audio encoding itself to have event markers which the `Audio` API reads and emits, sort of thing.

This code is running in the browser.

Comment: If your code is running inside an browser and the application is using HTML5, you can use the "ended" media event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event

Comment: @DeyanGeorgiev the ended media event works for subclips? How does that work? I'm not sure you're following what I'm asking. I'm not asking when the whole track ends, but when a part of it ends.

Comment: Imagine it this way, like I have a complete CD encoded into one mp3 file, how do I know when each song has ended?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event - maybe this can help? 
Basically when the playing position of a video has changed, it emits the current position of the video in seconds.

Note: The audio element inherits from HTMLMediaElement so the event must be presented for both audio and video

Comment: Take a look at this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-grothendieck-9f27h?file=/index.html

You can play the audio and see what will be printed in the console. Also you can manually move the audio to different second.      

You can implement logic and know if a song has ended, you can create a state array to know which songs have already been marked as ended so that you don't repeat the ending event for this song

Answer (score 0):

There is no Audio API type thing and the only way to know if a particular sound ends is to analyze the mp3 file, which would create even more lag. I would argue that your best bet is to use setTimeout, or perhaps the Date function.

**Using `new Date()`**

So my idea is create a date object on start, and then add the milliseconds until section ends. When that time has passed, the section has finished playing.